# Changed /system permissions, now corrupt

Tags: root-access, permissions, system

I own a Galaxy S5 and recently rooted it using SuperSU/TWRP.

I was trying to set the /system partition to read-write, but instead, I accidentally set the permissions of the /system folder to R W for User and nothing for Group or World (using Root Explorer)

Now my S5 won't boot - it gets to the boot screen and then into recovery (TWRP). Is there any way I could fix the permissions of the /system folder (without re-flashing the firmware)?

I tried using chmod 755/777 - didn't work...

Comment: sure that's the real issue (consider dm-verity)? *adb shell; mount /system -w; chmod -R 0755 /system/system;*

Comment: Hey alecxs, thanks for your reply! Luckily, I found an article which was a great help (https://androidforums.com/threads/changed-system-permissions.921257/) but I'll keep your answer just in case!